# Xcode iOS: Retrieving values from NSDictionary and displaying it in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview, nsdictionary

I want to display the json data obtained as:

```
NSDictionary *detail = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
```

and want to display it in UITextView(contact):

```
self.contact.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[detail valueForKey:@"Contact"];
```

But, I get the output as follows:

```
("Washington St, SD, CA")
```

detail is as follows:

```
(
    {
    Contact = "Washington St, SD, CA";
    Id = 1;
    Name = BJs;
 }
)
```

I understand since it returns an array, But how do I display it in a string without the round brackets?

Answer (score 2):

For dictionary access, you should ideally be using `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` (which has to do with key-value coding).

I don't know what your original JSON looks like, but if it is like:

```
{"Contact": "Washinton St, SD, CA", ...}
```

Then this should work fine. If not (i.e. it actually is an array in JSON), you might want to extract the first element (with `[... objectAtIndex:0]`, or joining the elements, or something else depending on your application).

Comment: I have just placed my detail (nSdictionary) in the question for your reference.